# vagrant box not available after update of virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, php, vagrant

I upgraded my virtualbox to 6.1.32-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.21.10.1 (I think, from 6.1.18 before) and now the vagrant boxes are not available any more in the browser via the box-IP like it used to work before for years.

if I `vagrant ssh` into the box I only see this in /var/log/syslog:

```
Mar 23 09:26:11 ubuntu-focal multipathd[485]: sda: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Mar 23 09:26:11 ubuntu-focal multipathd[485]: sda: failed to get sysfs uid: No data available
Mar 23 09:26:11 ubuntu-focal multipathd[485]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No data available
Mar 23 09:26:12 ubuntu-focal multipathd[485]: sdb: add missing path
...
```

which looks to me not so important, so I am lost, where to search for more evidence?

Maybe something in the network settings changed in the new version. These are  the settings of the VM in Virtualbox:

[image]
[image]
(the "invalid settings" only apply to the graphics adapter)

If I call the service inside the box with `w3m http://localhost` everything is there, so the problem must be something with the networking:

```
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:b8:29:08:49:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 84953sec preferred_lft 84953sec
    inet6 fe80::b8:29ff:fe08:4994/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:86:81:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.33.66/24 brd 192.168.33.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe86:8153/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

also calling `w3m http://192.168.33.66` works fine, while on 10.0.2.15 I don't get the webservice, only `ping 10.0.2.15` works on that IP.

How do I get access back in my browser on my host?

Comment: You've likely checked, but is there anything in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (or any of the other error logs) that point to the issue? 

Comment: yes, I also checked apache2/error.log and my local errorlog from the php  application I always use inside apache. but no clue yet

Comment: Apache and php is running, if I log in into the VM with `vagrant ssh focal64` I can use the php app in `w3m http://localhost`

Comment: The syslog errors are not related to your problem. you're safe to blacklist the devices ("^sd[a-z]") in `/etc/multipath.conf`. `http://localhost` is internal on your guest, but is the service also listening on 'Adapter 2'? Please try `w3m http://[IP from Adapter 2]` as well. (Maybe Adapter 1, too. Depending on your network setup)

Comment: @LupusE: I added this info to the question now

Comment: Maybe the IP-range was the problem, because the old vagrant didn't stop with the error, that the ip is out of the allowed range, like the latest version does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated vagrant to version 2.2.19 and re-installed the vbguest-plugin with

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vbguest
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

after VirtualBox 6.1.26 the allowed IP-Range changed to 192.168.56.0/21, so if you choose an IP between 192.168.56.2 and 192.168.59.254 the box is reacheable from the outside again

---

Just for info:
To get rid of the error messages in `syslog`, edit your `/etc/multipath.conf` file to match the following (this will also blacklists common other devices like CDRom drives etc.)

```
defaults {
    user_friendly_names yes
}
blacklist {
    devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st|sd[a-z])[0-9]*"
}
```

and restart multipathd:

```
systemctl restart multipathd
```